# Cart Webhooks / Flow Builder

Tags: cart, shopware

I'm currently working on a b2b project with shopware6 and need a webhook that calls my middleware / api, when a product is put into the cart.
I could not find anything in the flow builder that belongs to cart actions.
Do I need a special plugin?
Looking forward to your answers!
Best, Jule